# Why didn't std::ofstream in recursion work as expected?

Tags: c++, recursion, std, ofstream

Given codes as below:

```
int recur(int num);
int main()
{
    recur(5);
    return 0;
}    

int recur(int num)
{
    static unsigned count = 0;        
    //static
            std::ofstream log("log.txt",std::ios_base::app|std::ios_base::out);
    std::cout << count << "\n";
    log << count << "\n";
    ++count;

    if (num==0) return 0;
    num += recur(num -1);

    return num;
}
```

Output from `std::cout` :

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

Content of `log.txt`:

```
5
4
3
2
1
0
```

Why was it like so?

I tried to put `static` before `std::ofstream` just as commented in the function `recur`. Then it worked fine, exactly the same as the output from `std::cout`. Can anyone explain the rationale under hood?

Comment: The text is being put in the file when `log` is destroyed. They're destroyed in reverse order. `std::cout` lives for the entire program.

Comment: Also, some implementations flush `cout` on every `\n`, but not file streams. Adding `<< std::flush` after `<< '\n'` or using `<< std::endl` instead of `<< '\n'` should recover the original output sequence for `log`.

Comment: @chris Do you meang that nothing was written into the file before `log` was destroyed?

Comment: @Alan.W, Yes, the destructor calls `flush()`.

Comment: @celtschk I tried your suggestion. It works now!

Comment: @chris I need read a little bit more about the `std::ofstream`.Thx man!

Comment: Note however that creating a new stream in each recursion is very inefficient.

Comment: It would be better to not open and close the file so often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `recur` before `log` is closed in it's deconstructor. This means the file will be opened by multiple `ofstream`s at once, and the `ofstream`s earlier in the recursion do not get flushed as celtschk pointed out. It should work if you close the file before calling `recur`. It works if you declare `log` as `static` because then log only gets constructed once and therefore opened once. The code below adds a block to make sure `log`'s deconstructor is called before `recur` is.

```
int recur(int num)
{
    static unsigned count = 0;

    {
        std::ofstream log("log.txt",std::ios_base::app|std::ios_base::out);
        std::cout << count << "\n";
        log << count << "\n";
        ++count;
    }

    if (num==0) return 0;
    num += recur(num -1);

    return num;
}
```